# Printing Text to a Page in Java with Graphics2D

Tags: java, printing, word-wrap, graphics2d

This is the code I have now:

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) 
        throws PrinterException
{
    if(pageIndex > 0)
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
    g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

    String lineText;
    int lineSpace = 12;
    //Draw out each seperate line.
    for(int i = 0; i < storyText.length; i++)
    {
        //I split the text at "\n" and stored the lines in storyText.
        lineText = storyText[i];
        lineSpace += 15;

        graphics.drawString(lineText, 0, lineSpace);
        //What about g2d? Could or should I use that instead?
        //g2d.drawString(lineText, 0, lineSpace);
    }

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

This draws a line, then moves down some spaces (not sure what kind of units are used), then draws the next line. This is works, but the problem is that, horizontally, the text gets eaten by the margin on the left.

Does anyone have a solution to this? I just recently started tinkering with printing to pages with Java. Should I insert a newline character in the text to draw a shorter line of text? How would I figure out when to insert the newline character?

Or am I just doing this all wrong? Maybe a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in the `drawString()` method controls the x-coordinates of the beginning of that line of text. The unit it uses is points, with 72 points per inch. So to make the line start farther away from the left side of the paper, change that 0 to a larger number, perhaps 36, which would cause it to start half an inch from the left side of the physical page.

Another option is to use `pf.setImageable(x, y, sizeX, sizeY)`, where x and y are doubles representing the coordinates of the top left corner of the printable page, and sizeX and sizeY are doubles representing the dimensions of the printable page. Then use `g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY())` to set the origin of the `Graphics2D` object to the origin of the printable page. This way is probably easier.